ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYT
as i made to apps accounts and core . in accounts model i have created custom user and in core i made userpreference model i want to import accounts.models customuser but it gives error above mention
i have tried the name in install app as accounts and not resolve

As the helper message said, are you sure django is installed ? do you use virtualenv ?
You can verify if django installed by :
django-admin --version

If you are using virtualenv make sure it has been activated.
Otherwise, if django is installed but still not detected, try to add python libraries to PATH :
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/Installed/library/Python/to/site-packages
source ~/.bash_profile

